# Webmaster Sitemap error

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, google-search-console

I'm getting 1,509 errors reported for my sitemap in google webmaster tools.

The sitemap is generated by Wordpress plugin All in one SEO pack.

http://www.iltophotography.co.uk/site-map.xml

In order to rule out a problem with the plugin, I installed another plugin to generate the following sitemap:

http://www.iltophotography.co.uk/sitemap.xml

When added to webmaster tools it also errors.

The error is in the below image.

[image]

It must be something I've done, but for the life of me i can't work out what. Can anybody see anything obvious??

Thanks

Comment: It says that URL is invalid. Try out these URLs.

Comment: /gallery/daryl-rosie is a valid URL, but when clicking it via the link in webmaster tools it tries to open https://www.google.com/gallery/daryl-rosie/  ??

Comment: The sitemap should contain full URLs only, specifying the protocol and the main page.

Comment: agreed, that plugin seems to be messing the whole thing, use full URLs

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why it happened (or indeed why with 3 different sitemap plugins).

However editing the XML sitemap manually to sue full urls worked for google webmasters to accept it error free.